# Npm install cypress --save-dev fails with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, linux, cypress

I have been trying to install cypress as a dependency for my project following this documentation, however it fails with a code 1 and then reverts to using cmd to try to install it, which then ultimately fails.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#npm-install

```
dev123@DESKTOP-BG104ST:~$ npm init -y
Wrote to \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\dev123\package.json:

{
  "name": "dev123",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}


dev123@DESKTOP-BG104ST:~$ npm install cypress --save-dev
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\dev123\node_modules\cypress
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\dev123\node_modules\cypress'
npm ERR! CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
npm ERR! UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\index.js'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OfficeUser\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-13T16_32_19_739Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: This is an npm cli issue which is discussed in https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6280.